BulkMerge with child entity gives FK constraint
I'm using Entity Framework Extensions but can't get the simplest BulkMerge to work.
Basically I have a DbContext with Stock. Each Stock has a IList<StockPrice>. Whenever a the stock price is updated, it is added to the list of prices. It should also check if the price actually changed since last update. If the value is the same as the previous item, no update is necessary. The stock itself can also be updated with a new name.
My problem is that whenever I try to update the item I get a foreign key constraint error:

The MERGE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_StockPrice_Stock_StockId". The conflict occurred in database "Stock", table "dbo.StockPrice", column 'StockId'

To make it somewhat more difficult, I don't know the ID/PK of the Stock, which forces me to use ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression, which does seem to work.
However, I can't get the related entity to be saved. But whenever the child entity is involved I get a foreign key error.
Complete reproducible example
I currently have a semi-working way of doing this with EF which currently does the following steps:

Fetch the Stock-item from DB based on non-clustered index.
Check if the item exist. If it exists - update, otherwise create.
Check child items (price). If exists with same value - do nothing, otherwise create.
SaveChanges()

SaveChanges can handle several items at the time. But querying every item to memory (or a couple at the time) is not always very efficient. It handles millions of rows each run (in a transaction). Therefore I'm looking for a solution for doing it more efficient.

There's no Bulk Merge even as a concept, much less as an EF method. BULK INSERT is a special operation that inserts rows into a table as fast as possible, using minimal logging: instead of logging every new row to the transaction log, only data pages are logged. That's impossible for UPDATE/DELETE operations, which have to record the previous values of the row. The library you used isn't part of EF and its bulk methods don't even use EF. They generate table variables and then try to join these with the target table before performing operations.

That means there's no "simple" Bulk Merge. MERGE, just like UPDATE or INSERT, only works against a single table, so a MERGE can't insert both a Stock and StockPrices. EF alone can do that. If you have a detached Stock object with prices, when you call Update on it EF will start tracking both the Stock and the Prices in either the Added or Modified state, depending on the objects PK values. When you call SaveChanges EF will persist all of the changes

Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos. I'm aware of the limitations of EF. And somewhat aware of the MERGE capabilities of T-SQL. That's why I'm using the extension library, which according to documentation has support for merge with child operations. I would use "plain" EF if I could, but EF (as far as I can tell) don't support updating items without knowing the PK.

I didn't mention any EF limitations. I talked about MERGE's bugs, that non-EF extension's tricks and the fact that what you search for just doesn't exist IN SQL. Not EF or SQL Server, but in SQL generally. In all databases, only bulk imports have special treatment, because they're the only thing that can be optimized by reducing either transaction logging or, in MVCC, row version generation.

updating items without knowing the PK neither does MERGE. I explained what that library does. It's not related to ORMs at all, it's something you can do as well. It's also not efficient, which is why it's not used in ETL jobs. It inserts everything into a DataTable, which is the only thing that can be used as a table-valued parameter, thus caching all data in memory. Then it executes a MERGE command using the TVP as the source. That has several problems: MERGE isn't atomic and has lots of quirks. TVPs have no statistics either, so the resulting execution plans aren't optimal.

What ETL jobs do instead is perform a real bulk insert to a staging table, with the necessary schema, storage and indexes for the job, eg using SqlBulkCopy. You never have to cache the data into a DataTable, don't have to worry about TempDB performance, never have to wonder whether the tool generated the indexes you want. After that, they execute UPDATE then INSERT commands to update the target table. MERGE is rarely used due to its quirks. If you include the PK column in the update clause for example you get duplicate key violations even in SQL Server 2019.

ORMs like EF just aren't ETL tools. They're exactly wrong for the job, like comparing a sports car with a dump truck. When you control the table you can use techniques like partition switching to bulk insert and then instantly swap the data into the target. No need for MERGE. You can use table compression to improve IO, use columnstore indexes, clean up the data in place instead of pulling it over the network to the client

Partition switching may definitely be the way to go. Thanks for the advice.

Disclaimer: I'm the owner of Entity Framework Extensions and Entity Framework Plus
Here are 2 working fiddles for your scenario (I forked your reproducible example):

Solution #1
Solution #2

The problem in your reproducible example is that your StockPrice need to be updated using the StockID value but when you insert/update your Stock entity, you use a custom primary key and doesn't return the StockID value.
Solution #1
Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aaNFDG
In the solution #1, we added a reference to our other library: Entity Framework Plus, which has a dependency to Entity Framework Extensions.
In this solution, we choose to retrieve the Id (StockID) first to the database so as not to have to handle a custom primary key logic.
For this, we use the SyncPropertiesFromDatabaseValues method that allows you to sync the value you want.
So the following code has been added:
context.SyncPropertiesFromDatabaseValues(items, options =>
{
    options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new { x.MarketId, x.SectorId };
    options.SyncPropertyExpression = x => new { x.Id };
});  

After it run, your Stock entity will now have the right Id populated and you don't have to handle a custom key logic.
For the StockPrice part, we modified it to get these 2 lines:
bulk.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new { x.Price, x.StockId };
bulk.IgnoreOnMergeUpdateExpression = x => x.Id;

Since you want to add a new row and not update the existing row, you can use the combination of Price and StockId as your primary key.
And we ignore the Id as you don't want to update it.
Solution #2
Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zFiPOT
In the solution #2, we added this 2 lines for the Stock part:
bulk.ColumnOutputExpression = x => x.Id;
bulk.IgnoreOnMergeUpdateExpression = x => x.Id;

Since you use a custom key, we specifying our library that you want to return the Id and never update the value in the database which is very important as well.
For the StockPrice part, we did exactly what we did in the solution #1. We modified it to get these 2 lines:
bulk.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new { x.Price, x.StockId };
bulk.IgnoreOnMergeUpdateExpression = x => x.Id;

Since you want to add a new row and not update the existing row, you can use the combination of Price and StockId as your primary key.
And again, we ignore the Id as you don't want to update it.

BONUS: If you wish to update the price only when it's modified instead then you need to use MergeMatchedAndOneNotConditionExpression option such as:
bulk.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new { x.StockId };
bulk.MergeMatchedAndOneNotConditionExpression = x => new { x.Price};

So you use the StockId as you key and the row will only be updated if the price is different than the one in the database.

Not familiar with Z extension, but it would propose another one, note that I'm one of the authors.
Extension linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore has temporary tables support and full Merge syntax support via LINQ queries.
I have prepared funcion which merges stocks using temprorary tables:
public static async Task MergeStocks(List<Stock> items)
{
    await using var context = new StockContext(_options);
    await using var db = context.CreateLinqToDBConnection();

    await using var tempStocks = await db.CreateTempTableAsync(items, tableName:"tempStocks");

    var newIds = await context.Stock.ToLinqToDBTable()
        .Merge()
        .Using(tempStocks)
        .On((t, s) => t.MarketId == s.MarketId && t.SectorId == s.SectorId)
        .InsertWhenNotMatched(s => new Stock()
        {
            MarketId = s.MarketId,
            SectorId = s.SectorId,
            Name = s.Name,
        })
        .UpdateWhenMatched((t, s) => new Stock
        {
            Name = s.Name
        })
        .MergeWithOutputAsync((a, t, s) => new
        {
            t.Id,
            Key = new
            {
                s.MarketId,
                s.SectorId
            }
        }).ToListAsync();

    var newIdsDictionary = newIds.ToDictionary(x => x.Key);

    // Correct StockPrices
    foreach (var stock in items)
    {
        stock.Id = newIdsDictionary[new { stock.MarketId, stock.SectorId }].Id;

        foreach (var price in stock.Prices)
        {
            price.StockId = stock.Id;
        }
    }

    var stockPrices = items.SelectMany(x => x.Prices);

    await using var tempStockPrices = await db.CreateTempTableAsync(stockPrices, tableName: "tempStockPrices");

    await context.StockPrice.ToLinqToDBTable()
            .Merge()
            .Using(tempStockPrices)
            .On((t, s) => t.StockId == s.StockId && t.Price == s.Price)
            .InsertWhenNotMatched(s => new StockPrice
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                StockId = s.StockId,
                Price = s.Price,
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedBy = "Migration"
            })
            .MergeAsync();
}

Fully working Fiddler is here
